# How to not let the sender receive the message it sent?

Tags: c#, mvvm-light

Some of my classes send and receive message of the same type and I want them not to react on the messages they've sent.
The only way I see now is explicit sender's call to `Unregister()` prior sending the message and then calling `Register()` again after message is sent. This is fine but it requires quite a bit of boilerplate code.
It would be nice to have something like `Messenger.SendExceptSender(msg,sender)` where messenger ignores the sender if finds it in the list of the recipients.

Does IMessenger support this some way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I see, that's not possible. Neither the interface nor the implementation have facilities for this as they don't even know who the sender is.

The easiest approach would be to add the sender as a property to the message. This would greatly reduce the boilerplate code and would be safer than `Register` and `Unregister` in multi-threaded scenarios.

You could register your message like so:

```
messenger.Register(this, m => {
                                  if(m.Sender == this)
                                      return;
                                  YourMessageHandler(m);
                              } );
```

---

If this is a common scenario on your code you could even create an interface or base class for that `Sender` property and extension methods for `Register` and `Send` that handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You can include token with your message and where you want to register you also include token in registration routine.